# How does function `DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate:)` work?

Tags: ios, dateformatter

With some digging, and help from a thread on SO, I was able to figure out that if you set up a DateFormatter with code like this:

```
let locale = NSLocale.current
let format : String = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "j:mm.ss.SSS", options:0, locale:locale)!
print("format = \(format)")
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = format
```

You get a date formatter with a date string that adapts to the user's 12/24 hour clock setting.

If you run that code in the US with the device set to 12 hour time, you see the following on the console:

```
format = h:mm:ss.SSS a
```

If you set your device to 24 hour time, you instead see

```
format = HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

That makes sense.

However, once you assign the resulting format string to your date formatter, it should be fixed. I would expect the date formatter to generate 12 or 24 hour times until I explicitly change it's format string.

That is not what happens. If I switch to settings and change the clock settings from 12 to 24 hours, the date formatter magically starts producing 24 hour time strings. I can log the date formatter's format string, and it sill shows the 12 hour string "h:mm:ss.SSS a". What's going on?

Comment: I'd tend to say that's the way "j" is interpreted. I wouldn't think of "hh vs HH", but a a particular format. "This is a special-purpose symbol. It must not occur in pattern or skeleton data." says the doc http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns so it might be the case.

Comment: But if you look at the code I posted, I pass a date format containing a "j" to `dateFormat(fromTemplate:)`, and get back a concrete date format string. I then pass that to my DateFormatter in a normal `dateFormat` string. At that point, the fact that the "j" was passed in as a template is forgotten. All the date formatter knows is that I give it a dateFormat of `h:mm:ss.SSS a` or `HH:mm:ss.SSS`. That's the mystery.

Comment: @DuncanC - Were you able to find a solution for this? I am seeing similar issue.